# R spatial join-multiple criteria

Tags: r, spatial-join

I have two sf datasets and I want to find the 10 closest neighbors, based not only on distance but also on mathcing another column.
For example:

```
a = st_sf(a = 1:3, DD=c("d1","d2","d3"),
 geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
b = st_sf(a = 11:14,DD=c("d1","d2","d2"),
 geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
```

I would like to find the neighbors of "a" in "b" having the same value for "DD" col.
Currently I am using this [approach](https://github.com/michaeldorman/nngeo):

```
st_join(a, b, join = st_nn, k = 1, progress = FALSE)
```

But this joins points based on geometry only and I do not know how to get DD into account as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got values for both `DD` columns in the resulting joined `data.frame`, I'd just filter with `DD.x == DD.y`

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

a = st_sf(a = 1:3, DD=c("d1","d2","d3"),
          geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))

# modified b a little:
b = st_sf(a = 11:14,DD=c("d1","d2","d2", "d3"),
          geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2.9,3.1))))

st_join(a, b, join = st_nearest_feature, k = 1) |> 
  filter(DD.x == DD.y)

#Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
#Geometry type: POINT
#Dimension:     XY
#Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#CRS:           NA
#  a.x DD.x a.y DD.y        geom
#1   2   d2  12   d2 POINT (2 2)
#2   3   d3  14   d3 POINT (3 3)
```